# A more detailed directory listing in R?

Tags: r

A function I wrote generates an output file. Additional functions can take the content of that file (the name has a pattern that can be easily matched), and do more. Currently one could do the following:

```
function1(...)
# This will generate a file, say output_typea.md
# Then one could process this content further using
function2(input_file = 'output_typea.md')
```

However, since these two functions are meant to be run in sequence, I'd like to just let users call `function2()` and missing input would just read the most recent file matching the `dir(pattern = "*_type.md")`. Unfortunately it doesn't seem possible to sort `dir()` listings by date modified. All I need is the most recent file matching file name pattern. Any ideas?

Comment: I could use `system` to call `ls -t`, I'm not sure this would be portable to a windows user.

Comment: Use `file.info`. Something like `list.files()[order(ldply(list.files(), file.info)$mtime)]`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Look up the ctime (or other) and return the appropriate file:

```
x <- dir()
y <- file.info(x)
row.names(y[y$ctime==max(y$ctime),])
```

Comment: Thanks for the elegant solution.